# Selecting child css elements through Selenium not working

Tags: python, selenium

I recently started learning python. I started working on a small automation task for which I've chosen selenium. The task is, a .NET program will run and a profiler(I'm using Stackify Prefix) will log all the calls as below.
[image]

I've to loop through all the calls on left hand side and to click each one. Which will open a window on the right side with all the data. Now, I need data from the right hand side under "Request Started". Beside "Request Started", I've to find the plus symbol, click it and then fetch another div which contains the method name. Like below
[image]

While fetching the elements to click the plus symbol, the code is failing. Below is the code.

```
    from selenium import webdriver

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("http://localhost:2012")
    #colIdentList = driver.find_element_by_class_name('colIdent')
    for result in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('colIdent'):
        result.click()
        #wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
        for plus in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('collapser'):
            plus[0].click()
            for methodDiv in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('willnotrender'):
                value = methodDiv[0].text

    driver.close()
```

'collapser' is the class for that div which resides under multiple div and td.
I'm pasting XPATH for that component as a reference. But the XPATH is not always same and is different. I found two XPATHs for the element.

XPATH : 
1. /html/body/div[3]/div/ul/li[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6LI1.png)/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6LI1.png)/div[3]/div
2. /html/body/div[3]/div/ul/li[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6LI1.png)/div/div[3]/div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searches and a little help from my friend, [Mahesh Kosuri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11900864/mahesh-kosuri) I was able to complete the code. I was missing the fact that the webpage is having multiple frames. So, selenium was unable to find the element I was searching.

Below is the code which did the task for me.

```
  
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    import pandas as pd

    timetook,methodname,dbcalls=[],[],[]
    runnum,sheetname,counter=3,7,0
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("http://localhost:2012/")

    result in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('colIdent'):
        try:
            result.click()
            counter+=1
            if counter>8:
                driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('body > div.trace-list-area').scrollBy(0,75)")
        except:
            driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('body > div.trace-list-area').scrollBy(0,100)")
            result.click()
        driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_id('trace-frame'))
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'body > div.scroll-area > div > ul > li:nth-child(2) > div > div.flex-horizontal > div > button')))
        timetook.append(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('body > div.heading-trace-panel > div.tracebar-details > div > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) > div.tracebar-value')[0].text)
        driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('body > div.scroll-area > div > ul > li:nth-child(2) > div > div.flex-horizontal > div > button')[0].click()
        methodname.append(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#ui_0_stacks > li.logblock.backdrop-timing.logblock-message > div > div.flex-horizontal > div.prettyprint-container')[0].text)
        try:
            dbcalls.append(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('body > div.heading-trace-panel > div.tracebar-details > div > table > tbody > tr > td.stackNumbers > a > span')[0].get_attribute('data-badge'))
        except:
            dbcalls.append(0)
    driver.switch_to_default_content()

    df=pd.DataFrame()
    df["TimeTook"] = timetook
    df["methodName"]=methodname
    df["DBCalls"]=dbcalls


    df.to_excel("Timing Report "+str(runnum)+"_"+str(sheetname)+".xlsx")
    driver.close()
```